# Create a list of all Elements and their Valuekeys

Tags: python, flutter, appium, flutterdriver

I am currently facing the problem that i can't find a way to create a list of all elements and their Valuekeys, of a apk. Is there anyway that can be resolved?

Using the driver.find_elements(by=AppiumBy.CLASS_NAME,value='android.widget') leaves me with an Error message. So there has to be a way to do it with the Finder.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [get_attribute](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/attributes/attribute/), [get_text](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/attributes/text/), you can get a list of elements and then their values in a loop

Comment: What if i don't know their Values? I want to be able to gather all elements and their valuekeys on any app without knowing the values of the elements. Is that still possible?

Comment: that's how I described it to you, you don't know the value of the element, but you know its locator, you take the locator and get its value using the APIs described above

Comment: in short: you take a list of elements by a locator [find_elements](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/find-elements/), when you have a list of elements, you go through these elements in a loop and take their values. Then everything depends on the logic you need

Comment: Alright, but the way it is used on the website is deprecated, i am not sure where the 'self' infront of the driver comes from.

Comment: Hey again, i haven't figured out how to loop through the elements and give out their Valueskeys. Could you please send a code example on the method you described?